# geom_sf: plot multiple series

Tags: r-sf, geom

I have a sf polygon dataframe with multiple
series (T1, T2, T3, all on the same scale:
they're observations at different time points).
I can plot say T1 with

ggplot(map)+geom_sf(aes(fill=T1))

what I'd like to do is plot all three (T1, T2 and T3)
as facets (separate maps) on the same drawing.
I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I can't find it.
Can anyone tell me how? Thanks!

ADDED: Two additional notes on this question.
First, the data structure described above is
one that could be plotted using spplot, with
the T's being the arguments to spplot's zcol argument.
So in this connection, my question amounts to
asking how to convert an spplot structure to
be usable by geom_sf.

Second, suppose I use sf to read in a shp file
for say 20 polygons. I also have a data frame
consisting of stacked observations for these
same polygons, say for 3 periods, so the
dataframe has 60 rows. How do I merge these
in order to be usable? Can I just stack
3 copies of the sf structure, and than cbind the
dataframe (assuming the rows match up correctly)?

Answer (score 1):

At least in one sense this turns out to be very simple. Given a data structure (ds_sp) that can be plotted with spplot, you can just do the following:

ds_sf <- st_as_sf(ds_sp) # convert to sf form

plot(ds_sf[c("T1","T2")]) # plot the desired series

This isn't quite the same as using facet_wrap with ggplot, but at least it gives you something to work with.

ANOTHER LATER ADDITION : As to the longitudinal + facet_wrap issue, the following seems to work:

1. If necessary, create a data frame (df1) with the
   longitudinal data (longit), an area indicator (fips) and a time
   indicator (date) which will be used for faceting, and
   anything else you may need.
2. If necessary, create an sf-compatible version of
   the spatial geometry via st_to_sf, as new_poly .
   This will be of classes "sf" and "data.frame"
   and should have a spatial indicator matching fips
   in df1.
3. Merge the two:
   data_new<-df1<-dplyr::inner_join(df1,new_poly,by="fips",all.x=TRUE)
4. Now produce the plot
   ggplot(data_new)+geom_sf(aes(fill=longit,geometry=geometry))+facet_wrap(~date)
   and make adjustments from there.

Comment: I'm afraid this (later addition) didn't work for me - I get warnings about many-to-many relationships when I perform the join, and then the plot is just blank (albeit with the facets). Any other suggestions on using long data with geom_sf welcome!

Comment: Making progress now, by _removing_ the geometry aesthetic from the code - thanks for the help! Happy to upvote your answer if you edit the solution (don't know if it will also work for you?)